# Nested loops creating pattern (not diamond) in C

Tags: c, ascii-art

So for my assignment I have to take the inputs of length and width and print out patterns of "*" based on the inputs. The minimum height is 7 and only goes up by odd integers and width is any multiple of 6.

The basic format of the output using a height of 7 and width of 12:

```
************
************
***   ***   
   ***   ***
***   ***  
************
************
```

So basically the first and last 2 lines are straight through the entire width, with the odd numbered rows containing 3 asterisks followed by 3 spaces, until it reaches the end of the width. The even numbered rows start off with 3 spaces.

I've figured out how to print the first two lines using the following code:

```
do 
    {
        printf("*");
        ++i;
    }while(i<width);

    printf("\n");

    do 
    {
        printf("*");
        ++j;
    }while(j<=width);
    printf("\n");
```

But for the life of me, I cannot come up with the correct way to use basic nested loops to print out the inside pattern. I asked a programmer friend who is unfamiliar with C but wrote up a basic program in Java. I don't know Java and have tried to translate it but notice some big discrepancies in the logic between the two languages that is causing me headaches. Here is his code:

```
// LOGGING
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};


// PATTERN PARAMETERS
var rows = 6;
var cols = 7;

// hard code a space so html respects it
var space = "&nbsp;"

console.log("cols: " + cols + " rows: " + rows);

for (y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
    var line = "";
    for (x = 0; x < cols; ++x) {

        // First two and last two rows do not have patterns and just print filled
        if (y == 0 || y == 1 || y == rows - 1 || y == rows - 2) {
            line += "*";
        } else {
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                // Even row
                line += x % 6 < 3 ? "*" : space;
            } else {
                // Odd row
                line += x % 6 >= 3 ? "*" :  space;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(line);
}
```

Please help me or point me in the right direction!! I've searched online but can't seem to find a solution that's worked yet!

Edit- forgot to mention that all "printf" uses can only print one character at a time... Such as a single *

Edit edit- I GOT IT WORKING!!!! Thank you all so, so much for your input and guidance! Here's what I have that is working perfectly:

```
for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) 
    {
    printf("\n");

    for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) 
        {
        // First two and last two rows do not have patterns and just print filled lines
        if (y == 0 || y == 1 || y == height - 1 || y == height - 2) 
           {
           printf("*");
            }
        else 
        {
            if (y % 2 == 0)
            {
              if(x%6<3)
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }

            } else {
                // Odd row
                if(x%6>=3)
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
        }
        }

    }
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Consider using `putchar('*');` instead of `printf("*");`, but that is minutiae, not a serious problem.  The non-uniform repetition of code to print the first two lines is worrying, especially if there are two more copies of them for the last two lines of code.  Can you work out how to print interleaved triplets of spaces and stars for an arbitrary number of repetitions?  How can you determine whether to start with spaces or stars, and alternate between the two characters?  What happens if the width is not a multiple of three?

Comment: Yeah, the code my buddy provided gives those 4 lines proper placement but I can't for the life of me remember how I got it translated into C.

And I was going for an if statement using the "height" % 2 to determine if it's an even or odd number, but I can't seem to implement it correctly. 

I have some checks in prior lines to make sure the inputs are correct.

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java. But if you strip all the logging stuff and rename `var` to `int`, I don't see what these "big discrepancies" would be.

Comment: My apologies. And I guess I don't know how to implement the even/odd functionality seen as:

        line += x % 6 < 3 ? "*"

into a loop

(Please forgive my poor formatting, I've never posted on here before and I'm trying to figure everything out)

Comment: Do not use `do/while` loops, they are error prone even in cases where they seem to fit the purpose well.  In your code, you fail to produce empty lines when `width==0`, a valid input (0 is a multiple of 6).  Furthermore, you forget to initialize the loop counters.  Use the standard idiom: `for (i = 0; i < width; i++) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function with 3 arguments `n,a,b` that prints `n` groups of 3 of each argument `a` and `b` alternately.  You can call this function to print the 4 different kinds of lines.  You can make a loop to print the middle section repeatedly.  Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm afraid that is a bit over my head right now. Would it look something like one loop with two nested ones, each giving the different pattern? I'm sorry, I'm just still confused.

Comment: Do you know hoe to write functions?  The function would just have a single loop.  The main code would have a call to the function, a loop with 2 calls to the function with different arguments and a final call to the function.

Comment: Hint: the values for the `a` and `b` arguments could be `"***"` and `"    "`

Comment: I just started learning about functions, so barely. I apologize.

Comment: That's perfectly OK.  Everyone starts at 0 in C, including arrays ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int row, col, height = atoi(argv[1]), cols = atoi(argv[2]);
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            putchar(row < 2 || row >= height - 2 ||
                  col % 6 / 3 == row % 2 ? '*' : ' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation: print a * if you are printing the first 2 rows or the last 2 rows or if you are in the first half of a group of 6 chars on even rows and the other half on odd rows.

Comment: Remember that you need to understand how it works!  Otherwise, you don't gain anything from me doing your assignment.  As an exercise, you should rewrite the code to use an `if` statement instead of the `? :` ternary operator you probably haven't studied yet.

Comment: Working on that right now, I'd post what I came up with here but it's a bit too small of a space - I included it as an edit to my original post though!

Comment: Yes.  You got it, but you should use  `putchar` instead of `printf("%c"...)`

Comment: I'll look up how to do that. We've only learned how to print out statements using the "printf" though!

Comment: Yet you know about `? :` !  Amazing.

Comment: Haha, I looked it up while trying to research other things. I saw so many people mention it, especially when you said to try writing it into an if statement.

Comment: Generally, it would be better to combine your two answers into one, rather than creating two separate answers.  Given that you've created two answers, it is probably best to stay as you are, but for future reference, one answer per user per question is the norm these days.  It was even in the old days, except when playing with now-deprecated questions where multiple answers were desired.